# bash: check wheter docker service was already restarted

Tags: bash

Is there a way in bash to check whether docker service was already restarted? Here is my pseudo-code:

```
FILE=/etc/docker/daemon.json
i=1
retry=3
while [ $i -le $retry ];
 do
  if sudo ls [ -f $FILE ] && "docker not restarted"
  then
  sudo service docker restart
  break
  elif sudo ls [ -f $FILE ] && "docker already restarted"
  break
  else 
  sleep 10s
  i=$((i+1))
  fi
done
```

What could i use in place of `"docker not restarted"` and `"docker already restarted"`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple code using pgrep to detect if a process is running or not.

```
#!/bin/bash
var="docker"
if pgrep "$var" > /dev/null
       then   echo -e "\033[1;32m$var Running\033[0m"
       else   echo -e "\033[1;31m$var Stopped\033[0m"
fi
```

- special character is just to color. You don't need to use.